BigQuery Client Load Table from URI in Python doesn't work but using Pandas does
I have an ETL process that executes as a cloud function that reads a csv from a cloud storage bucket and writes it to a BigQuery Table.
def gcs_to_table(uri,table_id,project_id):

    logger.info(f'Writing data from {uri} to {table_id}.')
    
    # Construct a BigQuery client object.
    client = bigquery.Client()
    
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
        write_disposition=bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,
        source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,
        skip_leading_rows=1,
        allow_jagged_rows=True,
        max_bad_records=100,
    )
    
    load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
        uri, table_id, job_config=job_config
    )  
    
    load_job.result()  # Waits for the job to complete.
    
    destination_table = client.get_table(table_id)
    logger.info(f"Loaded {destination_table.num_rows} rows to table {table_id}".format())

This solution has been failing due to exceeding the 100 error limit, usually with an error like this one:
message: Error while reading data, error message: Unable to parse; byte_offset_to_start_of_line: 506943943 column_index: 11 column_name: "SomeColumn" column_type: DOUBLE value: "SomeString"
"SomeString" belongs in the previous column, so the columns are somehow getting misaligned during the load job. However, using notepad++, I've looked at the raw file and checked for obvious formatting issues with the csv such as mismatched quote characters or commas inside of string values, and I don't see anything that could be causing it.
I suspect this has something to do with my configuration and not the format of the CSV since when I run the process using pandas and pandas_gbq on that same CSV it works just fine:
def gcs_to_table(gcs_object,table_name,project_id):
    
    logger.info(f'Writing data from {gcs_object} to {table_name}.')
    
    dat = pd.read_csv(gcs_object)   
    
    dat.to_gbq(table_name, if_exists='replace')
    logger.info(f'Wrote DataFrame with shape: {dat.shape}.')
    

The pandas solution is much slower and can run into timeout issues, so I would prefer to keep using BigQuery client if I can get these issues resolved.
Any wisdom or even troubleshooting steps are greatly appreciated!

Try setting an explicit schema in the job config. My guess is that there's a misalignment between the interpreted csv type and the final table's column type.

Ah the idea was for it to work with slightly changing schemas. But it turns out my schema did change and that seems to have cause the issue because when I reran the job to create a new table instead of WRITE_TRUNCATE an existing table it worked.
